# refreshing rails helper method with ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Every time I try to update a helper method with rails ajax I get an undefined method error.

I have a count method in my articles helper that counts all comments for an article:

```
def count 
@article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])
@comments = Comment.where(:article_id => @article.id)
@comments.count
end
```

I then have it in my article show view to show the number of comments:

```
<span id="comments_count"><%= count %></span>
```

This all works fine but when I try and update it in my `create.js.erb` file I get an undefined method error:

```
$('#comments_count').html('<%= escape_javascript(count) %>');
```

The error I receive is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
    1: if ($(".replyform")[0]){
    2: $('.replyhere').after('<div class="comment"> <%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @comment) %> </div>');
    3: 
    4: $('#comments_count').html('<%= escape_javascript(count, locals: {count: @count}) %>');
    5: $('.replyform').removeClass('replyform');
    6: $('.replyhere').removeClass('replyhere');
    7:       $('.reply_form').fadeOut('fast', function() {
  app/helpers/articles_helper.rb:13:in `count'
  app/views/comments/create.js.erb:4:in `_app_views_comments_create_js_erb__499623995209914056_70100096787760'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

I have tried defining some locals like:

```
locals: {count: @count}
```

But that doesn't seem to help either.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems your `@article` is `nil` in `def count` because it must not be getting `params[:id]` when you are calling `count` method from your `create.js.erb`

Comment: add a if statement to check if there is an article before calling @article.id

Answer (score 0):

Add a if statement to check if there is an article before calling @article.id

```
def count 
  @article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  if @article
    @comments = Comment.where(:article_id => @article.id)
    @comments.count
  else
    # Do something
  end
end
```

Comment: That would fix the error but it doesn't solve the fact that @article is not being received?

Comment: Maybe it's not the ID param that you want to be searching by as you are trying to find_by_slug I doubt it's an ID.. ID's should only be used inside the normal ``.find`` method not ``.find_by_slug``